# Flutter - Change The content of push notification before display on screen in background mode

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a Chat App like WhatsApp.

My goal is to send a new push notification to every participant of the group when someone sends a message to a group.
Something like - "${contact name as saved in your phone} send a new message to the group!"

My problem is that I don't want to save in the database how each participant named all the other participants of the group (It will be a huge table of the Cartesian product
of all the participants)

I thought maybe it is possible to set the contact name of the sender from the flutter app just before the notification display on the screen.
I saw few examples for ios but none for Android.
Thanks for any kind of help :)